# stack implementation using array dynamic memory allocation code

Tags: c, arrays, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

**
code runs correctly but fails for index 0 & 1(45 & 76)
it prints junk numbers for stack[0] & stack[1]
i am using codeblocks
you can add
`push(item);`
if you want to as many times you want**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *stack;
int top=-1;
void push(int item);
void pop();
void peek();
int main()
{
    stack=(int*)calloc(top+1,sizeof(int));
    push(45);
    push(76);
    push(24);
    push(5);
    push(67);
    push(98);
    push(1009);
    push(6759);
    while(top!=-1)
    {
        peek();
        pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
void push(int item)
{
    top++;
    realloc(stack,(top+1)*sizeof(int));
    stack[top]=item;
}
void peek()
{
    printf("%d\t%d\n",stack[top],top);
}
void pop()
{
    top--;
    realloc(stack,(top+1)*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: You need to do `stack = realloc(stack, ...);`. Actually, you should assign it to a new variable, make sure it's not null, then assign it to `stack`.

Comment: @user3386109 There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Barmar Sure there is, it should simply be written as `stack=NULL`, since `calloc` is allowed to return a NULL pointer when the size is 0.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm not saying it's the best way to write it, but it should work fine as is.